# Include Option not Working with belongsTo and Sequelize

Tags: javascript, express, sequelize.js

I am trying to create an endpoint through which I can access the institute data and the related subject data. I am trying to do this with using the include option on the findAll command.

Model Definitions:

```
sequelize.define("institutes",
  {
    instituteId: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true,
      primaryKey: true
    }
    ,instituteName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true
    }
}

sequelize.define("subjectA", {
  instituteId: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    unique: true,
    references: { model: "institutes", key: "instituteId" }
  }
  ,subjectTeacher: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING
  }
}
```

Query Definition:

```
const {institutes} = require("../models")
const {subjectA} = require("../models")

module.exports = {

  async instituteData (req,res) {
    try {
      const info = await institutes.findAll({include: [{model: "subjectA", required: true}], limit: 12})
      res.send(info)
    } catch (err) {
      res.send({message: "This request did not work!"})
    }
  }
}
```

I also define `subjectA.belongsTo(institutes, { foreignKey: 'instituteId' , foreignKeyConstraint:true });` somewhere else in my project.

The result should be a SQL query like `SELECT * FROM institutes INNER JOIN subjectA on institutes.instituteID = subjectA.instituteId` but as of now the query does not return anything. If I omit the include option however the query works just fine.

Comment: I am not sure, a long time ago I tried the same thing. In the end it was a little stupid thing. Try to leave `unique: true,` at the `references` fields...

Comment: Thanks for the input @kmgt! Unfortunately it did not work.. Do you have any idea how to log something useful here? Because as far as it looks to me there is no I can work with.

Comment: I did not use `foreignKeyConstraint` so in my project it's just `subjectA.belongsTo(institutes, { foreignKey: 'instituteId' });`